# Get the values from one app to another in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on creating shopping cart. I am still in learning phase. I need to know how I can pass/use values from shop's models.py to cart's cart.py.

shop/models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

    delivery_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0,default=0)
    support_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0,default=0)
```

cart/cart.py : I think this is the file where I need to get delivery_price and support_price.  I dont know how I can get these two values. I want to add these prices and multiply it by quantity (something like `Product.delivery_price + Product.support_price * item.quantity` -> not sure about the way this is being done) How is this flow working? If anyone help me understand, it would be great.

```
class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):

    def add(self, product, quantity=1,update_quantity=False, support_req=False):
        """
        Add a product to the cart or update its quantity.
        """
        product_id = str(product.id)
        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 0,

                                     'price': str(product.price)}
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        else:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += quantity
        self.save()

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Iterate over the items in the cart and get the products
        from the database.
        """
        product_ids = self.cart.keys()
        # get the product objects and add them to the cart
        products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
        for product in products:
            self.cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product

        for item in self.cart.values():

            item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
            item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']

            yield item

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Count all items in the cart.
        """
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())

    def get_total_price(self):
        return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

I used code from https://github.com/twtrubiks/django-shop-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create an instance of your Product model. This is done by instantiate it like any other Python class (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/))

```
product = Product(100,10) #this is an example
```

Then you can add a product to a cart by using the built-in `add` method:

```
cart.add(product)
```

**Note**

You'll also need to instantiate a cart the same way as you did for your product.Then, you'll have access to other methods decalred in the `Cart` which handles calculating the total price.

And just for your understanding, you were asking how to *Get the values from one app to another in Django*. Well, in this case, since your passing a product object to cart via `product` parameter, you have acess to its attributes.